# PHP session_start() overwrites HTTP Expires header

Tags: php, session, http-headers, mod-expires

I am trying to set Expire header to 2 hours from access for text/html by using mod_expires like that:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive on
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"
   ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
</IfModule>
```

However when used with PHP:

```
session_start();
```

Expires header is being reset to:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

Any ideas how to avoid that overwrite by `session_start()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, looks like have found an answer:

```
session_cache_limiter('public');
session_start();
```

does the trick, thanks.

Comment: or pass an empty string to entirely stop PHP from screwing around with your caching headers.