# PHP cache header override

Tags: php, cache-control

I've been through over 100 answers here, lots to try, NOTHING working??

Have a PHP based site.  I need caching OFF for all .php files EXCEPT A SELECT FEW.

So, in .htaccess, I have the following:

```
ExpiresActive On
# Eliminate caching for certain dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl)$">
ExpiresDefault A0
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

Using Firebug, I see the following:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Sun, 02 Sep 2012 19:22:27 GMT
Expires Sun, 02 Sep 2012 19:22:27 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=3, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
```

Hey, Looks great!

BUT, I have a couple .php pages I need some very short caching on.

I thought the simple answer was having this added to the very top of each php page in which I want caching enabled:

```
<?php header("Cache-Control: max-age=360"); ?>
```

Nope.

Then I tried various versions of the above.  Nope.

Then I tried meta http-equiv variations.  Nope.

Then I tried variations of the .htaccess code along with the above variations, such as limiting it to:

```
# Eliminate caching for certain dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, max-age=0"
</FilesMatch>
```

Nope.

It seems nothing I do will allow a single .php to be cache enabled with the .htaccess code in place, short of removing the statements from the .htaccess file altogether.

Where am I going wrong? What do I have to do to get individual php pages to be cacheable while the rest remain off??

Thank you for any thoughts.

Comment: Just add one more FilesMatch section that will match your file that needs caching?

Comment: Hi, thanks - I was considering something like that, but the files that will need caching turned on are made dynamically from a template, and named freely - so I'm adding the header to the template itself.  I suppose I could try forcing a name prepend or something and trying a wildcard match - but seems I shouldnt have to go to that extreme??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently this has no answer.  So, my solution at this point is to eliminate the .htaccess code altogether, and apply explicit headers to each file.  A pain in the you-know-what but it's time to move on.  If anyone has a more elegant solution that can work with an .htaccess default please feel free to share... thanks

Answer (score 3):

So I know I'm late.. maybe too late. but I came across a simular problem, and I thought I'd share my solution.

Basically, I turned ExpiresActive Off for every file I didn't want to be cached (or have different caching times than my static resources). It looked something like this:

```
ExpiresActive On

<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl)$">

  # This makes sure that no cache headers can be set,
  # but does not generate an error when trying to.
  ExpiresActive Off

</FilesMatch>

# Your normal caching here
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

Now over in your PHP script, you should be able to insert caching headers without them being overwritten by your .htaccess file, just like you were doing

```
<?php header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 360) . ' GMT'); ?>
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

This answer had the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4521120/2685496

Little did I know that `session_start();` by default overwrites your Cache-control and Expires headers with values to ensure the page is not cached.

You can use `session_cache_limiter('public');` before `session_start();`, like Marcin suggests, or you can just put your `header();` statements after `session_start();`.

Comment: You're wrong. The issue here is that first php sets the headers, then apache sets the headers, so the problem is that apache is overwriting all of the cache headers.