# .htaccess specific url changes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-expires

I've a small, but hard to understand problem with .htaccess in CMS system.

I've mod expires, that cache stuff on whole website, but I don't want to cache stuff in /admin URL, I can't make another .htacess, couse I've MVC structure and no real directory that could hold all my admin stuff.

I've found  directive, but it only works in server configuration and I want it to work on different hostings, so only in htaccess file.

EDIT- Rewrite

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ![0-9]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: you should be more precise, like which CMS you are using, what is the MVC that has no "real directory", etc. But if you are using .htaccess, you could simulate a directory behaviour, by setting specific rules that will apply only to certain URL syntaxes

Comment: It's local produced CMS, that have a lot of complicated dir's to admin stuff in difrent real directrories. And my question is just that, how to simulate a drectory behaviour for cerain URL syntaxes. I want all that is having /admin/* url

Comment: it also depends on what you have already in your .htaccess file (url rewrite for example can mess some path directives). It should be possible using `<directory /your/path>` or `<directoryMatch regex>`, where you can add directive that will apply to certain paths of your URL. See here for details http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory , i could write a precise answer tonight if you still have trouble

Comment: Directory and DirectoryMatch is not working in htacess file. I will update my question with rewrites.

Comment: sorry then, that's why i never used it :p i will chek that tonight if not answered before.. with fileMatch maybe?

Comment: I will try, but I don't think  so. Please help if you will have time.

Comment: you're right, filesMatch won't work here. If i understand your code right, your admin section falls into the last rewrite and goes to `index.php/admin`? If so and the answer don't work for you, can't you set the cache headers conditionally with php in your index? It seems that php cannot override htaccess, so maybe the answer there can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239225/php-cache-header-override

Comment: Thanks, this is great idea. I will try it asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your Expires directive using a `<if>` directive with an expression to match against `/admin`:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /^\/admin\//">
    # Your expiry directives
</If>
```

Comment: It gives me Error 500

Comment: @Aksebkit Which version of apache are you on?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact URL then you can try this pattern.

```
RewriteRule ^facebook/get/(.*)?$    http://$1 [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^wrapper/share/(.*)?$ http://example.com/wrapper/share/$1 [NC,R]
```

**This will check for URL where *<-any-value->facebook/get/<-any-value2->* and then will send to the <-any-value2->**

**Like**

```
RewriteRule ^stats/(.*)$ admin/dashboard.php?mode=openstats&event_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**If URL has *stats/<--any-value-->* then it will redirect/open admin/dashboard.php **

If your URLs doesn't have exact value but you do know the URL slot pattern then you can try this.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ wrapper/index.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```